# how to wrap PIMPL, hiding raw pointers

Tags: c++

In Sean Parent's going native talk, he recommends using as few pointers with implied ownership as possible. He states that it is trivial to wrap a PIMPL implementation at 00:53:06.
https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Cpp-Seasoning

I'm not sure I understand what he means here. I thought Implementation pointers were always hidden in the class that uses them. Is there some additional layer that can make PIMPL more convenient that I'm missing?

Edit:
Earlier he says `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` both count as raw pointers. That's why I'm confused, I'm aware that `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` simplify resource handling. I'm unaware of any method to hide them further.

Comment: You hide it from the class implementation itself and save yourself from having to write the Group of 3|5 by using something like `unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Use a [`unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr). The class using the pimpl idiom is "owning" the raw pointer and it is good practice to have as few owning raw pointers as possible.

```
class T {
public:
    T() : impl{} {};
private:
    struct impl;
    std::unique_ptr<impl> pImpl_;
}
```

Comment: `impl` is an incomplete type, so the `unique_ptr<impl>` will complain. Add a deleter: `struct impl_deleter { void operator()(impl*); };` then `std::unique_ptr<impl, impl_deleter> pImpl_;`; the `t.cpp` file can implement `void T::impl_deleter::operator()(impl* ptr) { delete ptr; };`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a unique pointer. Since you can create a unique pointer with an incomplete type, it is your best bet. You should not forget to add destructor, since the type is incomplete. If you do not add the destructor, the compiler will create a default one and will require the complete definition of the incomplete type. Since it is impossible at this stage you will get a compile error. Below you can see an example of pimpl using a unique_ptr.

```
// Foo.h
class Foo {
    public:
        Foo();
        ~Foo();

        void implementationToHide();
    private:
        class FooImpl;
        std::unique_ptr<FooImpl> _impl;
};
```

The implementation details

```
// Foo.cpp
class Foo::FooImpl {
    public:
        void actualImplementation(const Foo &f);
};

void Foo::FooImpl::actualImplementation(const Foo &f) {
    // some secret implementation
}

Foo::Foo(): _impl(std::make_unique<Foo::FooImpl>()) 
{

}

Foo::~Foo() {
    
}

void Foo::implementationToHide() {
    _impl->actualImplementation(*this);
}
```